# Conversion of MySQL procedures into PostgreSQL functions

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures, database-migration

We are trying to migrate my existing [MySQL-5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-29.html) database to [PostgreSQL-9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/index.html).
Able to do the table structure and data migration using python scripts.
I found [mysql2pgsql](https://pythonhosted.org/py-mysql2pgsql/) and [DBConvert](https://dbconvert.com/mysql/postgresql/) and the [mysql2pgsql](https://pythonhosted.org/py-mysql2pgsql/) is enough to migrate schema/data but not able to migrate the stored procedure.

Is there any way to convert/migrate the stored procedures as well, I am also thinking that It would be probably difficult to convert the already written sql logic for any business application. But want to try if anything is there already which can work smoothly.

Comment: Curious - how many procedures are you looking to migrate?

Comment: @Nicarus Since I am trying to migrate a running business application DB which has more than 100s of stored procedures so can't think of doing it manually

Comment: I was asking as some trial software have limitations - not to suggest that you do it manually. Have you looked into this?: https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert

Comment: @Nicarus Sorry I misunderstood,  Fullconvert is also able to do the table, data &  constraints migrations only nothing more.